# Unix "sort" command for a CSV file

Tags: bash, sorting

I have a .csv file with entries that look like:

```
"29 January 2016 19:33 EST","Mary Z Allen",...
"01 February 2016 16:29 EST","Kendra A Zimmerman",...
"22 February 2016 12:08 EST","Shawn Baker",...
```

The first CSV field (date/time) is assigned by the system, and always has exactly five words.  The second CSV field(name), consists of one or more words.

I want to sort by the final word in the second field.  For this example, the desired order after sort would be

```
"29 January 2016 19:33 EST","Mary Z Allen",...
"22 February 2016 12:08 EST","Shawn Baker",...
"01 February 2016 16:29 EST","Kendra A Zimmerman",...
```

No doubt, with a little effort, one could come up with a bash, awk, or python script to perform this kind of sort.  But is there a way to use the sort command directly?

The specific Unix version I am using (from /proc/version) is

```
Linux version 3.13.0-79-generic (buildd@lcy01-11) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:28:32 UTC 2016
```

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue! with decorate/sort/un-decorate pattern.

```
$ awk -F, '{t=$2; sub(/.+ /,"",t); print t"\t"$0}' file | sort | cut -f2-

"29 January 2016 19:33 EST","Mary Z Allen",...
"22 February 2016 12:08 EST","Shawn Baker",...
"01 February 2016 16:29 EST","Kendra A Zimmerman",...
```

print the last word of the second field as key, sort and remove the dummy key.

Comment: How did it take me three hours to type essentially the same response?  That'll teach me to get distracted by a long lunch. :)  I'll just contribute that the cut should probably be "`-f2-`" in case there's a tab in the data.

Comment: thanks for the answer - probably would have taken me 3+ hours to work it out.

Comment: Tried it out on the full database, realized that some of the records had space(s) at the end of the second field.  Taking a hint from your answer, changed the awk script to '{t=$2; sub(/ +"/,"",t);sub(/.+ /,"",t); print t"\t"$0}' (space at the beginning of the first regexp).  Seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The sort command can split into fields, so if you just wanted to sort by name, you could do something like `sort -t, -k2`.  But for this, what you'll have to do is to split the lines out.  Here's a very simplistic example of extracting the thing you want to sort upon, prepending it to the line, sorting on only the first field, then removing that field.

```
user@machine[/home/user/dev]
$ cat testfile
"22 February 2016 12:08 EST","Shawn Baker",...
"29 January 2016 19:33 EST","Mary Z Allen",...
"01 February 2016 16:29 EST","Kendra A Zimmerman",...
user@machine[/home/user/dev]
$ paste <(cut -d, -f2 testfile | awk '$0=$NF') testfile | sort -k1,1 | cut -f2-
"29 January 2016 19:33 EST","Mary Z Allen",...
"22 February 2016 12:08 EST","Shawn Baker",...
"01 February 2016 16:29 EST","Kendra A Zimmerman",...
```

Note that this code to extract the desired field makes the bad assumption that the the first and second fields won't contain a comma: `cut -d, -f2 testfile | awk '$0=$NF'`  If they may, then you'll want to replace it with something smarter.  The rest of the code should be fine, as paste and cut defualt to tabs, and sort/awk are using whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` to copy the lastline in front of your line. That way sorting is easy and you only need to delete the extra data.
The `sed` command will need to look for strings without a double quote using `[^"]*`, resulting in

```
sed 's/\("[^"]*","[^"]* \)\([^"]*"\)/\2=\1\2/' testfile | sort | cut -d= -f2
```